Extract value from a cell of an Workbook without opening it
I have an Excel file named Excel_File.xlsx which is saved in the same location of my present Excel Workbook, and that file contains a matrix of numbers of rows 100 and columns 1000.
I want to extract the value of the cell from 4th column and 5th row without opening it. The size of the file Excel_File.xlsx is quite huge so I restrain from opening it.
I used below VBA code without success
MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "[" & "\Random_Number_Matrix.xls" & "]" & strSheet & "'!" & Range("A1").Address(1, 1, xlR1C1))

Could you please help with the right VBA code?
I also want to pass the row and column indices without the cell name i.e. instead of passing D5, I want to use the index number (5,4)
Any pointer will be very helpful.
Thanks for your time.

A CSV file doesn't have any worksheets until you open it in Excel...

Okay. Thanks for this information, I didnt know that. However how can I make that work?

You will need to read the csv loop the rows and then parse the string yourself.

...or open the file in Excel and read all the data into an array (you can turn off screenupdating while doing that).  Either way, "without opening the file" is not possible here: you need to open it to read it.

@TimWilliams Will it possible if I save all numbers CSV_File.csv in CSV_File.xlsx, and use that instead? In that case how?

Previous posts: https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+read+cell+from+closed+file+site:stackoverflow.com

Maybe this is of any help.

@Storax These examples all appear to be using Absolute path of the source excel file. However I am looking for the Relative path, as the Absolute path may change in future and I want my code should still work

ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Excel_File.xlsx" if the file is in the same folder as the workbook with your code

@TimWilliams I tried with MsgBox ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "[" & "\Random_Number_Matrix.xls" & "]" & strSheet & "'!" & Range("A1").Address(1, 1, xlR1C1)) - but with this my current Excel workbook closes suddenly

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78347185/6600940

Does this answer your question? Importing a value from closed workbook

Trying to read a single cell value from a closed workbook is possible using ExecuteExcel4Macro. Please, try using the next piece of code:
Sub ExgtractONECellValFromClosedWB()
  Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, sheetName As String, ws As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = cells(5, 4)
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'sheet where to return
  
  strPath = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"
  strFile = "Excel_File.xlsx"
  sheetName = "Sheet1"

  'extract the necessary value in "A2" of the active sheet:
  ws.Range("A2").value = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("'" & strPath & _
      "[" & strFile & "]" & sheetName & "'!R" & rng.row & "C" & rng.column)
End Sub


If you need to have your final result in a spreadsheet, you can also use formulas. The code in a similar style as above (not restricted to a single cell):
Sub ReadFromClosedWB_ByFormula()
  Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, sheetName As String, ws As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Cells(5, 4)
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 'sheet where to return
  
  strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
  strFile = "Excel_File.xlsx"
  sheetName = "Sheet1"

  'extract the necessary value in "A2" of the active sheet:
  ws.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "='" & strPath & _
      "[" & strFile & "]" & sheetName & "'!R" & rng.Row & "C" & rng.Column
End Sub

If you prefer a value, you can easily convert it also:
ws.Range("A2").Value = ws.Range("A2").Value

